# IE9: Permanently accept untrusted certificate

Tags: internet-explorer-9, certificate, https, ssl-certificate

When accessing a website via HTTPS which has an untrusted certificate, Internet Explorer 9 always shows me the following error message:

[image: Certificate warning]

Is there a way to import the certificate permanently, so that I don't have to click away this message every time?

I don't have access to the root certificate the certificate was signed with.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Follow the instructions linked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681695/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-internet-explorer-8-to-accept-a-self-signed-certifica

It's pretty much the same for IE9, except you have to press the Alt key on your keyboard to get the menu bar to pop up.

Comment: I found I could not follow step 9, <<Click on "Certificate Error" at the right of the address bar and select "View certificates".>> Instead, I right clicked on the page, clicked "Properties" then "Certificates". That worked great.

Comment: This solution (installing the untrusted certificate into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities) is _extremely_ problematic, security-wise. You are not adding an exception for a webpage, you are trusting the certificate for all reasons and purposes, including impersonating gmail.com or your bank.